# Android animation in custom view not playing while interacting

Tags: android, animation

I'm experimenting with making a chart in Android, and I'm basing my code on this  [example from Google](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/8536493/samples/training/InteractiveChart/src/com/example/android/interactivechart/InteractiveLineGraphView.java).

So the chart can be zoomed and panned freely by the user, but now I'm trying to animate a size change on the viewport of the chart. The animation works fine on its own, but the problem for me is that it cannot play while I'm interacting with the chart, so if I'm currently zooming the animation will not play until I'm done. I want the animation to play out while I'm zooming or panning. How can I achieve this?

This is my animateable RectF.

```
public class AnimatableRectF extends RectF {
public AnimatableRectF() {
    super();
}

public AnimatableRectF(float left, float top, float right, float bottom) {
    super(left, top, right, bottom);
}

public AnimatableRectF(RectF r) {
    super(r);
}

public AnimatableRectF(Rect r) {
    super(r);
}

public void setTop(float top){
    this.top = top;
}
public void setBottom(float bottom){
    this.bottom = bottom;
}
public void setRight(float right){
    this.right = right;
}
public void setLeft(float left){
    this.left = left;
}
```

}

And this is how I start the animation.

```
ObjectAnimator animateTop = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mCurrentViewport, "top", mCurrentViewport.top, smallest - margin);
animateTop.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
        postInvalidate();
    }
});

AnimatorSet rectAnimation = new AnimatorSet();
rectAnimation.playTogether(animateTop, animateBottom);
rectAnimation.setDuration(500).start();
```